# ajax/jquery - trigger event on click but wait with actual triggering until page loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using a jquery function to trigger a click on a li element, when page has loaded. It works fine, but as my pages are also loaded using ajax, this event is not being triggered again, when clicking through page navigation. Now I tried to add the same event on click - which doesn't work, as the content is not ready. It worked adding a timeout, but my understanding is, that this is a rather dirty solution, considering different load times on various internet speeds.

My function on page load (which works):

```
$j(window).load(function(){
        $j("div.filter_holder ul li:first").trigger('click');
});
```

Now I was trying to actually do the same thing on click on the li element by selecting its ID and then wait with the trigger, until page is loaded (by ajax):

```
$j( '#nav-menu-item-87' ).click(function() {
    $j(window).load(function(){
        $j("div.filter_holder ul li:first").trigger('click');
    });
});
```

Am I completely wrong? Does this actually work at all? I couldn't find anything related to this specific situation... :/

Thanks, guys!

Jay

EDIT: Following the comment from Александр Лазарев I've read myself a bit into ajaxSuccess() - http://api.jquery.com/ajaxsuccess/ - but didn't get much further. I simply can't figure out, how to listen for a specific success message. It should fire only, when a certain page is being loaded (/portfolio/) and this is, what I found inside ajax.js, that came with the theme.

```
function loadResource(url) {
"use strict";

var me = $j("nav a[href='"+qode_root+url+"']");

var animationTime = $j('body').hasClass('page_not_loaded') ? 0 : PAGE_TRANSITION_SPEED;
var direction = me.hasClass('up') ? 'up' : 'down';
var direction2 = me.hasClass('left') ? 'left' : 'right';

var exitFinished = false;

$j.ajax({
    url: qode_root+url,
    dataType: 'html',
    async : true,
    success: function (text, status, request) {
        function insertNewPage () {
            //don't slide in until the old page has gone
            if (!exitFinished) {
                return window.setTimeout(insertNewPage, 100);

            }
            //slide in new page

            slideInNewPage(text, direction, direction2, animationTime, { 
            oncomplete: function () {
                    ajaxSetActiveState(me);
                }
            }, url);
            balanceNavArrows();
        }
        insertNewPage();
        firstLoad = false;
        //document.location.href = qode_root + '#/' + url;
        if (window.history.pushState) {
            var pageurl = qode_root + url;
            if(pageurl!==window.location){
                window.history.pushState({path:pageurl},'',pageurl);    
            }
            if(typeof _gaq !== 'undefined') {
                _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', qode_root+url]);
            }
        } else {
            document.location.href = qode_root + '#/' + url;
        }
    },
    error: function () {

    },
    statusCode: {
        404: function() {
            alert('Page not found!');
        }
    }
});

//slide out old page; timeout is a fix beacause of transition delay
slideOutOldPage(content, direction, direction2, animationTime, { 
    oncomplete: function () {
        exitFinished = true; 
    }
});

if($j('body').hasClass('page_not_loaded')){$j('body').removeClass('page_not_loaded');}

}
```

Any ideas? :/

Comment: you are wrong .. tyre below

 $j(window).load(function(){
   $j( '#nav-menu-item-87' ).click(function() {
        $j("div.filter_holder ul li:first").trigger('click');
   });
 });

Comment: You should declare call trigger once again, in ajax success method.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I've edited my previous question and added code from ajax.js. Do you have any ideas? Cheers!